# Why is Go Colly Collector not always finding SVG tag?

Tags: go, web-crawler, go-colly

I am trying to write a simple web scraper in Go using Colly. The program is supposed to visit an earnings calendar for a particular date range on yahoo finance and then spiral out and visit each Stock Ticker page that shows up in the list. The scraper is then supposed to collect specific information on each individual ticker page.

Three pieces of information I am trying to grab is the style on 3 SVG tags that populate on the individual stock ticker pages. These SVGs each indicate the short, medium, and long term outlook for the stock (I am interpreting what each "outlook" is based on the css style being applied to the SVG).

When I run my program, Colly will spider through and only capture the styling for the SVG tags for about 30% of the stock ticker pages. The rest come back empty. Every time I run the program the list of Stocks where the SVG styles actually populate is different. Why is this happening? See sample output and src code below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gocolly/colly/v2"
    "log"
    "strings"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type Stock struct {
    Url            string
    TickerSymbol   string
    CompanyName    string
    PerformanceOutlookShort string
    PerformanceOutlookMid string
    PerformanceOutlookLong string
}

var mu sync.Mutex

func main() {
    var stockData = make(map [string]*Stock)

    c := colly.NewCollector(
        colly.UserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36"),
        colly.AllowedDomains("finance.yahoo.com"),
        colly.MaxBodySize(0),
        colly.AllowURLRevisit(),
        colly.Async(true),
    )

    // Set max Parallelism and introduce a Random Delay
    c.Limit(&colly.LimitRule{
        DomainGlob: "*",
        Parallelism: 2,
        Delay: 500 * time.Millisecond,
    })

    log.Println("User Agent: ", c.UserAgent)

    // Before making a request print "Visiting ..."
    c.OnRequest(func(r *colly.Request) {
        log.Println("Visiting", r.URL.String())

    })

    // Unique Identifier for the Earnings Page
    // Collect the list of stocks, initializing each one in a map
    c.OnHTML(`.simpTblRow`, func(e *colly.HTMLElement){
        temp := Stock{}
        temp.CompanyName = e.ChildText(`td[aria-label="Company"]`)
        temp.TickerSymbol = e.ChildText(`td[aria-label="Symbol"]`)
        temp.Url =e.ChildAttr("td>a", "href")
        stockData[temp.TickerSymbol] = &temp
        e.Request.Visit("https://finance.yahoo.com" + temp.Url)
    })

    // On each stock ticker page collect the relevant information and update each map item
    c.OnHTML(".finance.US", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {

        // Skip this callback if we are on the earnings calendar page
        if !strings.Contains(e.Request.URL.Path, "/quote/"){
            return
        }

        // Get the current stock in the map that matches the one on the ticker page
        stockNameTickerString := e.ChildText("#quote-header-info h1")
        justTicker :=stockNameTickerString[strings.Index(stockNameTickerString, "(")+1:strings.Index(stockNameTickerString, ")")]
        currStock := stockData[justTicker]
        log.Println(currStock.TickerSymbol)

        
        // The LAST 3 Stats are not always captured for each stock... why?
    

        // Capture Short Term Outlook
        currStock.PerformanceOutlookShort = e.ChildAttr(`#chrt-evts-mod > div:nth-child(3) > ul > li:first-child > a svg`, "style")

        // Capture Mid Term Outlook
        currStock.PerformanceOutlookMid = e.ChildAttr(`#chrt-evts-mod > div:nth-child(3) > ul > li:nth-child(2)> a svg`, "style")

        // Capture Short Term Outlook
        currStock.PerformanceOutlookLong = e.ChildAttr(`#chrt-evts-mod > div:nth-child(3) > ul > li:nth-child(3)> a svg`, "style")

    })

    c.Visit("https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/earnings?from=2021-02-28&to=2021-03-06&day=2021-03-04")
    c.Wait()

    for _, v := range stockData {
        fmt.Println(v.TickerSymbol, " - ", v.PerformanceOutlookShort)
        fmt.Println(v.TickerSymbol, " - ", v.PerformanceOutlookMid)
        fmt.Println(v.TickerSymbol, " - ", v.PerformanceOutlookLong)
    }
}

Sample Output:

FENC  -  
FENC  -  
FENC  -  
GMRE  -  
GMRE  -  
GMRE  -  
SBOW  -  
SBOW  -  
SBOW  -  
NMM  -  
NMM  -  
NMM  -  
WB  -  fill:#ff4d52;stroke:#ff4d52;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
WB  -  fill:#1ac567;stroke:#1ac567;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
WB  -  fill:#ff4d52;stroke:#ff4d52;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
VSEC  -  fill:#ff4d52;stroke:#ff4d52;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
VSEC  -  fill:#464e56;stroke:#464e56;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
VSEC  -  fill:#1ac567;stroke:#1ac567;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
GEENQ  -  
GEENQ  -  
GEENQ  -  
TZOO  -  
TZOO  -  
TZOO  -  
FCRD  -  fill:#ff4d52;stroke:#ff4d52;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
FCRD  -  fill:#1ac567;stroke:#1ac567;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
FCRD  -  fill:#1ac567;stroke:#1ac567;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
SYNC  -  
SYNC  -  
SYNC  -  
RNET  -  
RNET  -  
RNET  -  
INFI  -  
INFI  -  
INFI  -  
GCP  -  fill:#ff4d52;stroke:#ff4d52;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
GCP  -  fill:#ff4d52;stroke:#ff4d52;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
GCP  -  fill:#ff4d52;stroke:#ff4d52;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
FRPH  -  
FRPH  -  
FRPH  -  
SIGA  -  
SIGA  -  
SIGA  -  
NWPX  -  fill:#ff4d52;stroke:#ff4d52;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
NWPX  -  fill:#1ac567;stroke:#1ac567;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
NWPX  -  fill:#1ac567;stroke:#1ac567;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
MICT  -  
MICT  -  
MICT  -  
SLNO  -  
SLNO  -  
SLNO  -  
AAMC  -  fill:#ff4d52;stroke:#ff4d52;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
AAMC  -  fill:#ff4d52;stroke:#ff4d52;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
AAMC  -  fill:#464e56;stroke:#464e56;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
PKDC  -  fill:#ff4d52;stroke:#ff4d52;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
PKDC  -  fill:#ff4d52;stroke:#ff4d52;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
PKDC  -  fill:#ff4d52;stroke:#ff4d52;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
NWLI  -  
NWLI  -  
NWLI  -  
MNDO  -  fill:#ff4d52;stroke:#ff4d52;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
MNDO  -  fill:#1ac567;stroke:#1ac567;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
MNDO  -  fill:#1ac567;stroke:#1ac567;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
FTSI  -  
FTSI  -  
FTSI  -  
AIKI  -  fill:#ff4d52;stroke:#ff4d52;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
AIKI  -  fill:#1ac567;stroke:#1ac567;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
AIKI  -  fill:#1ac567;stroke:#1ac567;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
CULP  -  fill:#ff4d52;stroke:#ff4d52;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
CULP  -  fill:#464e56;stroke:#464e56;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
CULP  -  fill:#464e56;stroke:#464e56;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
HURC  -  fill:#ff4d52;stroke:#ff4d52;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
HURC  -  fill:#1ac567;stroke:#1ac567;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
HURC  -  fill:#1ac567;stroke:#1ac567;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
EQ  -  
EQ  -  
EQ  -  
HRTG  -  
HRTG  -  
HRTG  -  
SALM  -  
SALM  -  
SALM  -  
OXFD  -  
OXFD  -  
OXFD  -  
CMTL  -  fill:#ff4d52;stroke:#ff4d52;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
CMTL  -  fill:#ff4d52;stroke:#ff4d52;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
CMTL  -  fill:#1ac567;stroke:#1ac567;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
DXYN  -  fill:#ff4d52;stroke:#ff4d52;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
DXYN  -  fill:#464e56;stroke:#464e56;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
DXYN  -  fill:#1ac567;stroke:#1ac567;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
SD  -  
SD  -  
SD  -  
BXMX  -  fill:#ff4d52;stroke:#ff4d52;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
BXMX  -  fill:#1ac567;stroke:#1ac567;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
BXMX  -  fill:#1ac567;stroke:#1ac567;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
BXC  -  fill:#ff4d52;stroke:#ff4d52;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
BXC  -  fill:#ff4d52;stroke:#ff4d52;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
BXC  -  fill:#464e56;stroke:#464e56;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
SHIP  -  fill:#ff4d52;stroke:#ff4d52;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
SHIP  -  fill:#1ac567;stroke:#1ac567;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
SHIP  -  fill:#ff4d52;stroke:#ff4d52;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
NRP  -  
NRP  -  
NRP  -  
GWRS  -  
GWRS  -  
GWRS  -  
WPG  -  
WPG  -  
WPG  -  
MLR  -  
MLR  -  
MLR  -  
OXSQ  -  fill:#1ac567;stroke:#1ac567;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
OXSQ  -  fill:#1ac567;stroke:#1ac567;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
OXSQ  -  fill:#1ac567;stroke:#1ac567;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
UTF  -  fill:#ff4d52;stroke:#ff4d52;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
UTF  -  fill:#ff4d52;stroke:#ff4d52;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
UTF  -  fill:#1ac567;stroke:#1ac567;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
SMHI  -  
SMHI  -  
SMHI  -  
MNKKQ  -  
MNKKQ  -  
MNKKQ  -  
FIZZ  -  fill:#ff4d52;stroke:#ff4d52;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
FIZZ  -  fill:#ff4d52;stroke:#ff4d52;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
FIZZ  -  fill:#1ac567;stroke:#1ac567;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
RLH  -  fill:#464e56;stroke:#464e56;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
RLH  -  fill:#ff4d52;stroke:#ff4d52;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
RLH  -  fill:#1ac567;stroke:#1ac567;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
YY  -  
YY  -  
YY  -  
ANFIF  -  fill:#1ac567;stroke:#1ac567;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
ANFIF  -  fill:#ff4d52;stroke:#ff4d52;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
ANFIF  -  fill:#ff4d52;stroke:#ff4d52;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
CIA  -  fill:#1ac567;stroke:#1ac567;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
CIA  -  fill:#1ac567;stroke:#1ac567;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
CIA  -  fill:#1ac567;stroke:#1ac567;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
SFE  -  
SFE  -  
SFE  -  
APT  -  fill:#ff4d52;stroke:#ff4d52;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
APT  -  fill:#464e56;stroke:#464e56;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
APT  -  fill:#ff4d52;stroke:#ff4d52;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
AIV  -  fill:#ff4d52;stroke:#ff4d52;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
AIV  -  fill:#ff4d52;stroke:#ff4d52;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
AIV  -  fill:#1ac567;stroke:#1ac567;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
FLMN  -  fill:#ff4d52;stroke:#ff4d52;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
FLMN  -  fill:#1ac567;stroke:#1ac567;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
FLMN  -  fill:#1ac567;stroke:#1ac567;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;
```

Comment: have you tried temporarily dumping the html output of the page and comparing it with what colly collects?

Comment: Yes I have - for the stock tickers where the SVG style can be collected, the SVG element is there in the source HTML as expected. And for those where the style can't be collected, the SVG element is not there. What I can't figure out is why sometimes the SVG is present and other times it is not.